# Installing the StatET plugin in Eclipse

Tags: 10.10, eclipse

I'm trying to install the StatET plug-in with Ubuntu 10.10.

In Eclipse, I go to help, install software, and put in the following domain.

http://download.walware.de/eclipse-3.7

However, I get the following error message.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: IDE Framework Extensions 0.10.0.b201106190930E37sw (de.walware.ecommons.ide.feature.group 0.10.0.b201106190930E37sw)
  Missing requirement: Miscellany of ECommons Core Packages 0.10.0.b201106190930E37sw (de.walware.ecommons.coremisc 0.10.0.b201106190930E37sw) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.6.0' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Miscellany of ECommons Core Packages 1.0.0.b201108092000sw (de.walware.ecommons.coremisc 1.0.0.b201108092000sw) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.6.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IDE Framework Extensions 0.10.0.b201106190930E37sw (de.walware.ecommons.ide.feature.group 0.10.0.b201106190930E37sw)
    To: de.walware.ecommons.ltk.core [0.10.0.b201106190930E37sw]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: LTK Core 0.10.0.b201106190930E37sw (de.walware.ecommons.ltk.core 0.10.0.b201106190930E37sw)
    To: package de.walware.ecommons 0.0.0
```

Can anyone help me diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Clearing this one up, you say you're using eclipse 3.7.  The error message states that it requires the eclipse 3.6 run-time.

This issue no longer exists.  I installed the newest version of the available plugin as directed by their website.  It now supports 3.7.